# Shiro: Is it possible to get the URL in doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, jersey, shiro

I am trying to create a RESTful web service using Jersey framework on google appengine. I am using apache shiro for authentication.

Let's say I have the following scenario:

1. There is a admin user pre-configured which creates other user and provides the username and password offline to each of those users.
2. For the normal users, there are a number of REST APIs. There is one API: 
   `GET /tokenInfo`  which should use username and password for authentication and return a UserId and token as response.
3. For all the other REST APIs, I want the credential used for authentication to be the UserId and Token instead of Username and password.
4. So basically it a scenario where the credential pair used for authentication varies based on the API.

How can I achieve this in shiro. From what I understand, doGetAuthenticationInfo() passes the credentials sent by the client and expects you to validate, but in this case, I need to know which API is called. So is there a way to get the URL?
If no then what other way is there to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you would need to create a custom filter, to build the type of token you want to pass to your realm, take a look at one of the defaults as an example:
https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#default-filters

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand that. What is "build the type of token you want to pass", if I understand correctly, the token that is passed is  credential pair  received in the request.
To clarify my problem again:
I basically have two sets of credentials pairs:
1. Username(String/Long) : Password(String)
         OR
2. UserId(Long) : Token(String)
For one set of APIs, I want to use credential pair # 1, for another set of APIs, I want to use credential pair # 2. 
So when I receive a request with some credentials, how do I know which pair to authenticate against without knowing the URL?

Comment: Ok,I think I got it now. I have created a custom filter which extends "BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter". In that I have overriden the "createToken()", method and the object it returns has the URL also. With this, I am able to get the URL in the "doGetAuthenticationInfo()" function.